# Repair sagging ceiling that has heat strips

Tags: repair, ceiling

House was built 1975 - 1980 and has heat strips in ceiling. My hallway is sagging, I am not sure where the heat strips are.  Are they protected so that a screw will not damage them?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't want to punch any fasteners through the drywall until you know exactly where the elements are located. The strips are not protected against that. What exactly is sagging? Has the drywall let loose, or is it a framing issue?

Comment: One consideration is to check the bathroom vent lines, one place didn't vent the bathrooms to the exterior, causing the insulation to soak up the moisture, eventually (over years) the weight was so great that it pulled out the drywall nails that were holding the sheets in.

Comment: Voting to close. Questions outstanding; OP hasn't been back.

Answer (score 1):

In the pacific North West the "cable heat wires" are laying on the sheet rock between the trusses. These are easy to damage and usually have a insulation above them. I would suggest checking them before working on the sheet rock a few homes I have repaired had some kind of adhesive holding the cable in place if you have this kind of install they are difficult to remove but can be separated with patience.